# JSON object returned from Controller renders in new screen

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I looked at other questions with same issues. I tried all the suggestions but it doesnt seem to work.
I am using MVC4.I am calling an action method on form submit using post method in jquery. But when the controller retruns JSON, it is loaded as a new page like below

```
{"ok":true,"message":"success"}
```

instead of returning to the point where I want it to.

This is my cshtml page. (precisely just the begin form and the button)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SendMail", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "HomePage", id = "HomePage" }))
{
   <input id="BtnSend"  type="submit" value="SEND MAIL" >
}
```

Here is my jquery script to do the ajax post.

```
  $('#HomePage').submit(function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: this.method,
                            url: this.action,
                            data: $(this).serialize(),
                            dataType: 'html',
                            success: function (returndata) {
                                alert(returndata.Data);
                            }
                         });


    });
```

Based on suggestion from another post, I tried this.

```
 $('#HomePage').submit(function () {
        var form = $($("form")[0]);

        form.submit(function () {
            $.post(form.attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function (result, status) {
                alert(result.Success);
            });
        }, "json");
    });
```

This doesnt help either. 
Here is my controller action method( just the signature and the return statement removing the other logic)

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SendMail()
    {

       TryUpdateModel(EmailHomeViewModel);
        // i have removed rest of the logic here
       return Json(new { ok = true, message = "success" }, "text/plain", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


    }
```

I have verified that I have added unobstrsive-ajax library in my page. I have other ajax calls to controller in the same page. They work fine. So only difference is Here I am doing a form submit. Can someone suggest if I am missing something here? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (untested):

```
$('#HomePage').submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault(); // prevent default form submit behaviour
                    $.ajax({
                        type: this.method,
                        url: this.action,
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        dataType: 'html',
                        success: function (returndata) {
                            alert(returndata.Data);
                        }
                     });


});
```

Comment: thank you very much @geedubb. It works after stopping default submit behaviour